# Tokenizing a string in Prolog using DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

Let's say I want to tokenize a string of words (symbols) and numbers separated by whitespaces. For example, the expected result of tokenizing `"aa 11"` would be `[tkSym("aa"), tkNum(11)]`.

My first attempt was the code below:

```
whitespace --> [Ws], { code_type(Ws, space) }, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

letter(Let)     --> [Let], { code_type(Let, alpha) }.
symbol([Sym|T]) --> letter(Sym), symbol(T).
symbol([Sym])   --> letter(Sym).

digit(Dg)        --> [Dg], { code_type(Dg, digit) }.
digits([Dg|Dgs]) --> digit(Dg), digits(Dgs).
digits([Dg])     --> digit(Dg).

token(tkSym(Token)) --> symbol(Token). 
token(tkNum(Token)) --> digits(Digits), { number_chars(Token, Digits) }.

tokenize([Token|Tokens]) --> whitespace, token(Token), tokenize(Tokens).
tokenize([]) --> whitespace, [].
```

Calling `tokenize` on `"aa bb"` leaves me with several possible responses:

```
 ?- tokenize(X, "aa bb", []).
 X = [tkSym([97|97]), tkSym([98|98])] ;
 X = [tkSym([97|97]), tkSym(98), tkSym(98)] ;
 X = [tkSym(97), tkSym(97), tkSym([98|98])] ;
 X = [tkSym(97), tkSym(97), tkSym(98), tkSym(98)] ;
 false.
```

In this case, however, it seems appropriate to expect only one correct answer. Here's another, more deterministic approach:

```
whitespace --> [Space], { char_type(Space, space) }, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

symbol([Sym|T]) --> letter(Sym), !, symbol(T).
symbol([])      --> [].
letter(Let)     --> [Let], { code_type(Let, alpha) }.

% similarly for numbers

token(tkSym(Token)) --> symbol(Token).

tokenize([Token|Tokens]) --> whitespace, token(Token), !, tokenize(Tokens).
tokenize([]) --> whiteSpace, [].
```

But there is a problem: although the single answer to `token` called on `"aa"` is now a nice list, the `tokenize` predicate ends up in an infinite recursion:

```
 ?- token(X, "aa", []).
 X = tkSym([97, 97]).

 ?- tokenize(X, "aa", []).
 ERROR: Out of global stack
```

What am I missing? How is the problem usually solved in Prolog?

Comment: One comment on naming: I suggest the name `tokens//1`, so that you have `token//1` and `tokens//1`, in analogy to `digit//1` and `digits/1`. This way, you avoid an imperative name which would suggest that the nonterminal can only be used in one direction. `tokens//1` is more declarative and makes sense also when the nonterminal is needed in other directions.

Comment: Two very good resources for learning DCGs: first, [Markus Triska's DCG Primer](http://www.metalevel.at/dcg.html); then, take a look at the (somewhat difficult to find) [collection of generally useful DCG rules](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl?show=src) available as a part of the SWI-Prolog source. Both are quite small and contain a lot of very useful code examples / recipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem is that in your second version, `token//1` also succeeds for the "empty" token:

```
?- phrase(token(T), "").
T = tkSym([]).
```

Therefore, unintentionally, the following succeeds too, as does an arbitrary number of tokens:

```
?- phrase((token(T1),token(T2)), "").
T1 = T2, T2 = tkSym([]).
```

To fix this, I recommend you adjust the definitions so that a token must consist of at least one lexical element, as is also typical. A good way to ensure that at least one element is described is to split the DCG rules into two sets. For example, shown for `symbol///1`:

```
symbol([L|Ls]) --> letter(L), symbol_r(Ls).

symbol_r([L|Ls]) --> letter(L), symbol_r(Ls).
symbol_r([])     --> [].
```

This way, you avoid an unbounded recursion that can endlessly consume empty tokens.

Other points:

Always use `phrase/2` to access DCGs in a portable way, i.e., independent of the actual implementation method used by any particular Prolog system.

The `[]` in the final DCG clause is superfluous, you can simply remove it.

Also, avoid using so many `!/0`. It is OK to commit to the first matching tokenization, but do it only at a single place, like via a `once/1` wrapped around the `phrase/2` call.

For naming, see my comment above. I recommend to use `tokens//1` to make this more declarative. Sample queries, using the above definition of `symbol//1`:

```
?- phrase(tokens(Ts), "").
Ts = [].

?- phrase(tokens(Ls), "a").
Ls = [tkSym([97])].

?- phrase(tokens(Ls), "a b").
Ls = [tkSym([97]), tkSym([98])].
```

Comment: I tried querying `phrase(tokens(Ls), "a b").` in SWI-Prolog, but it produced an error message: `ERROR: Type error: \`list' expected, found \`"a b"' (a string)`.

Comment: SWI-Prolog is unfortunately not an ISO-conformant system. Either invoke it with the command line flag `--traditional`, or add the following to your program: `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).`. Even more readable is: `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`. I recommend to add this to all your programs where you use DCGs.